# How to create index with nested list

Tags: c#, linq, comments, ravendb

I have a collection of documents called question.
My model is as follows

Questions contain comments. A comment has a status and a date.

For each question I to make the status of the most recent comment a root level property.

I know that i need a static index and i have tried various things.I know i can do it for a single question something like

```
(from x in question.Comment
orderby x.date 
select x.status).Take(1).FirstOrDefault()
```

But i cant figure out how to make this an index over the whole collection.

I have also tried querying the results to return questions with a comment of the status i am looking for but this throws a negated Any() error.

```
from x in Session.Query<Question>()
 where !(from y in x.Comments
        where ListOfStatusesCommentShouldntHave.Contains(y.Status) select y).Any()
 select x)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly this should work:

```
var results = Session.Query<Question>()
    .Select(q => q.Comments.OrderBy(c => c.Date).FirstOrDefault().Status);
```

Comment: thanks that would return the most recent status. But how to a make that a ravendb index. I then want to query that index to get the questions whose most recent comment status is in a  specified list.

Answer (score 0):

We've done something similar and used a Map Reduce index to query a nested property over an index. To do that you need to create an index extending `AbstractIndexCrationTask<T, U>` like this:

```
public class DiscussionTopicPosts_Index : AbstractIndexCreationTask<DiscussionTopicPosts, DiscussionTopicPosts_Index.Post>
{
    public class Post
    {
        public string DiscussionTopicPostsId { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }

        public Guid PostedByLearnerId { get; set; }

        public DateTime InsertedUTC { get; set; }
    }

    public DiscussionTopicPosts_Index()
    {
        Map = topicPosts => from p in topicPosts
                            from post in p.Posts
                            where post.IsEnabled == true
                            select new
                            {
                                DiscussionTopicPostsId = p.Id,
                                Id = post.Id,
                                Message = post.Message,
                                PostedByLearnerId = post.PostedByLearnerId,
                                InsertedUTC = post.InsertedUTC,
                            };

        Store(x => x.DiscussionTopicPostsId, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.Id, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.Message, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.PostedByLearnerId, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.InsertedUTC, FieldStorage.Yes);

        Sort(x => x.Id, SortOptions.Int);
    }
}
```

Note that the `Map` has another `from` statement that drills down into a nested property called `Posts` that is on the `DiscussionTopicPosts` documents.